# django query-set regex giving extra results

Tags: python, mysql, sql, regex, django

I am trying a make a regex query on django query set. I have a column having values like

`'67,42,16', '16,42,67,70', '4,11,21,78', '12,45,6,22'`

I want to extract columns having either '4' or '70' in them. Here is my regex

```
 _regex = r"(^|(\d*,)+)%s((,\d*)+|$)" %('4|70')
```

and my query

```
dict(Table.objects.filter(column__regex=_regex).values_list('row_id','column'))
```

Its returning the following result

```
{1563864L: u'67,42,16', 1563804L: u'16,42,67,70', 1563863L: u'4,11,21,78'}
```

I am expecting this result `1563804L: u'16,42,67,70', 1563863L: u'4,11,21,78'`

Not sure why I am getting `1563864L: u'67,42,16'` as a result

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Without going into you regex. All of you string's contains a `4`.

Comment: Hey Gogoi, if i change my regex to _regex = r"(^|(\d*,)+)%s((,\d*)+|$)" %('4') ...i get the expected result {1563863L: u'4,11,21,78'} ...which is correct.

Comment: Got Issue..regex should be r"(^|(\d*,)+)(%s)((,\d*)+|$)" %('4|70')

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess what you're trying to do, as it's always difficult to reverse a regular expression's original intent. Try this.

```
_regex = '(^({0}),.+)|(.+,({0}),.+)|(.+,({0})$)'.format('4|70')
```

And a little more pythonic:

```
acceptable_values = [4, 70]
regex_template = '(^({0}),.+)|(.+,({0}),.+)|(.+,({0})$)'
_regex = regex_template.format('|'.join([str(v) for v in acceptable_values]))
```